# Stop user role changing only when canceling a subscription

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm using WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin and I would like to stop user role changing only when canceling a subscription.

I found a code snippet [**here**](https://gist.github.com/thenbrent/8870062#file-wcs-do-not-update-role-php):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_update_users_role', '__return_false', 100 );
```

… which Stop WooCommerce Subscriptions Changing a User's Role. This will stop role changing when purchasing a subscription too.

What I would like is to stop user role changing **only when canceling a subscription**. 
Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [**`woocommerce_subscription_status_cancelled`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/#section-2) action hook *(without any guaranty as it's untested)*, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_cancelled', 'keep_user_role_unchanged_on_cancelled_status' );
function keep_user_role_unchanged_on_cancelled_status(){
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_update_users_role', '__return_false', 100 );
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Reference: [Subscription Status Change Actions](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/#section-2)

Answer (score 0):

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_cancelled', 'wcs_maybe_make_user_inactive_for', 10, 1 );
```

Use this in your active theme functions.php